# Rails generates CSS file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I have the file buy.css.scss

Rails keeps creating "buy.css" in the same folder, which breaks all of my icons (because I'm using asset-url instead of url)

What gives? Can I stop it making the .css file?

Answer (score 0):

Think you cant do. It creates these files, but you decide which ones you actually pull into your application in your buy.css.scss file. There is sprockets syntax at the top (*= require_self
*= require_tree.)